# changing a post status from custom status to pending. - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my `review` custom post type, posts should be reviewed twice before publishing.
1) by the administrator and 2) manager.
Thats why i have registered a new custom post status - `pending_review`.And `pending` is already built in wordpress.

So now when the review is taken from frontend its `post_status` is `pending_review` and its only shown to `admin` not to `manager`.And when its transformed from `pending_review` to `review` then its shown to manager.Then when manager approve / publish the post its status is changed to `pending` to `publish`

Now the ques is how i can change status from `pending_review` to `pending`.When publish button is pressed in `pending_review` status.The post is directly published.

### I tried this code

```
function reviewed_by_admin( $new_status, $old_status, $post ){
    if( 'review' == get_post_type( $post ) ){
        wp_transition_post_status( 'pending_review', 'pending', $post );
    }
}

if(current_user_can( 'administrator' )){
    add_action( 'pending_review_to_pending', 'reviewed_by_admin', 10, 3 );
}
```

But not works

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wonder if the underscore in your custom post status may be causing some problem? Maybe it `should not have an underscore` in it.

What I would try is the following (untested):

```
function on_all_status_transitions( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // you may add any conditionals regarding roles here ....
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'pending_review' ) {
        $post->status = 'pending';
    }
     return $post;
}
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3 );
```

Let me know if it helps. More information on the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: Not working bro. :( here is image what would be `pending_review` : http://prntscr.com/dbovfi

Comment: Did you try to name it pendingreview without underscore? There MUST be some possibility to hook into the post status change and within this hook you must be able to do the logic in order to prevent a post from changing its post status from pending_review to publish directly.

Comment: Yes I tried.but not working.and the post is being published